# Stuck with a formula for generating boolean strings

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm trying to make a formula on Google Sheets that would help me utilize all added keywords from column B into a sourcing boolean string that would include OR and "". (Example "Keyword1" OR "Keyword2" OR "keyword 3" ).

So far, I was able to come up with this, which starts from field B8(based on my doc):

`=IF(B8<>"",""""&B8&"""","")&IF(B9<>""," OR "&""""&B9&"""","")&IF(B10<>""," OR "&""""&B10&"""","")&IF(B11<>""," OR "&""""&B11&"""","")&IF(B12<>""," OR "&""""&B12&"""","")&IF(B13<>""," OR "&""""&B13&"""","")&IF(B14<>""," OR "&""""&B14&"""","")&IF(B15<>""," OR "&""""&B15&"""","")`

But, the problem that I'm facing, is that if I want to increase the number of keywords beyond 8, I have to manually create every new IF line, one by one, which would take a lot of time (let's say I would have over 500 keywords that I'd like to use and I would need to create 500 BNUMBER lines....).

Is there any way to remodify this formula so that it would include all the keywords that were pasted in the column, no matter the number, or to somehow auto-generate the formula to, let's say, B1000?

Comment: Hi Dean it would be great if you'd [edit] your question to explain why you are trying to do this. See [The XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) It may be that understanding the purpose of the  "sourcing boolean string" will help inform the approach that makes the most sense with your actual goal in mind.  It is a bit difficult for understand the application as the keywords can be compared without concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter()` and `join()`, like this:

```
=join(" OR ", filter("""" & B8:B & """", len(B8:B)))
```

See [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197) and [join()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3094077).